# Gridview's list of page indexes are spread apart

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView with paging enabled. The list of page indexes are not listed close to each other. Instead, there's like 80px between each page index. Is there a property which controls this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a 'table {width: 100%} css declaration which caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PagerStyle, here is a skin I use

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" SkinId="gridviewSkin" BackColor="White" CssClass="lightTable">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#EAEEEF" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F9F8" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="tablePagingFooterDirectory" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Also it renders as a table by default, so this css can be used

```
.tablePagingFooterDirectory td { padding: 1px; background-color: #EAEEEF;  }
tr.tablePagingFooterDirectory table td { color: #434F5E; border:none; }
```